# вывести последних и первых дат по группе sql запросом

Tags: sql

Не получается вывести последние и первые даты для "m" и "w" sql запросом.  не указывая вручную "m" и "w" чтоб для любых групп работало. групп может быть больше двух

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: база данных какая?

Comment: Что не получается? Где попытки?

Comment: Обычная группировка, обычные MIN и MAX... вообще не понимаю сути проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я постараюсь без uniona

```
select 
      min(CASE WHEN sex='m' THEN birthday END) AS minM, 
      min(CASE WHEN sex='w' THEN birthday END) AS minW,
      max(CASE WHEN sex='m' THEN birthday END) AS maxM, 
      max(CASE WHEN sex='w' THEN birthday END) AS maxW
from table
```

или так

```
select 
      min(birthday) AS min, 
      max(birthday) AS max,
      sex
from table 
group by
sex
```

Comment: А если чуть обобщенее. не указывая вручную "m" и "w" чтоб для любых групп работало. групп может((

Comment: @AlihanUrumov обновил для вас ответ посмотрите

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, соль вопроса в том, как сжедать это ОДНИМ sql запросом.

Я могу предложить только неизящный способ, основанный на использовании union:

```
    select min(birthday), null from table where sex='m'
    union
    select null, max(birthday) from table where sex='w'
```

Кто лучше?

Comment: А если чуть обобщенее. не указывая вручную "m" и "w" чтоб для любых групп работало. групп может быть и больше